# Strange poorly progammed puzzle game for the PSP, with Dragon Kids. and towers

Tags: story-identification, video-games

What I can remember of this game is that two brothers were minding their own business when suddenly some strange mini hurricane thing takes them into two towers, and if you die, this guy pops up and says “You are not my son.” I remember playing it on my PSP, during the early 2000’s.

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (video game) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are most likely looking for the much-lambasted PSP game  [*Bubble Bobble Evolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_Bobble_Evolution), in which brothers trapped in dragon suits get pulled into the "*Towers of Entertainment*".

While I can't find anything current (the game is from 2008), here is [an archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160510123339/http://socksmakepeoplesexy.net/index.php?a=sticktop10) (warning NSFW) that confirms the death mantra...

> "You are not my son".

Comment: What does it even mean?